# $L$ commutes with translations and rotations $iff$ it has constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

This is an exercise from Folland's Introduction to Partial Differential Equations.

> Suppose $L$ is a partial differential operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $L$ commutes with translations if and only if $L$ has constant coefficients.

This means to prove that $L$ commutes with translations iff $\displaystyle L=\sum c_a\partial^a$.

This is actually part of the proof about someone else has asked here [Questions about partial differential operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49521/questions-about-partial-differential-operators) . Holland starts the proof, but doesn't proves its initial statement in the proof and left it as an exercise - which I cannot solve.

Comment: Translations in the basis directions are generated by $\partial_{i}$ - you can compute the commutator of this with $L$ explicitly.

Comment: I second Daniel Littlewood's advice. Alternatively, a representation-theoretic approach would use Schur's lemma, but that's probably out of scope of the book you are reading

Comment: @DanielLittlewood How? I don't think I understand how to find the explicit form

Comment: Yesterday, I made you the remark that 6 questions a day means that you have not time to work seriously on each one. Today you are already at 5 questions... This is not the way one can work for a long time in mathematics: you need to find people able to work with you just around you.

Comment: @Cure Do you know the definition of the commutator of two differential operators?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Do you mean $[U,V]=UV-VU$? So in this case I would compute $[\partial_i, L]=[\partial_i, \sum c_a \partial^a]$ and then $(\partial_i \sum c_a \partial^a)\phi - (\sum c_a \partial^a \partial_i)\phi= (\partial_i \sum c_a \partial^a\phi) - (\sum c_a \partial^a \partial_i\phi)$ ?

Comment: Right, and presumably you know the product rule? And that second partial derivatives commute?